# Method does not override method from its superclass Android Error when coding todo list app

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and creating Android apps. When working on a to-do list app using this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/) I ran into the error

> Method does not override method from its superclass

Any fixes?

```java
package com.moltaexlips.todolist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, Menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                Log.d(TAG, "Add a new task");
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Well I have tried looking at the tutorial exactly and it seems I'm following everything although I could be wrong.

Comment: Then it's either do not put super. on the method call in the sub class or write the required method in the sub class. Or one of your written methods should not have @Override on it (because there is not such a method in the super class).  Which method?

Comment: Post the complete error message. There is no information about the method in the error you posted.

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu return `true` because you have a options menu to inflate